# I cannot get my vector to display its contents C++

Tags: c++

Main method...I use a for loop to try to display the contents of my vector but it doesnt work? I am trying to copy my list into a vector then change one element of the vector and then output the results in descending order. I have checked my vector and it seems to be just copying in the last element of the list. How do I fix that and get it to display my vector?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Stocks.h"
#include <list>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    list<Stocks> myList;
    Stocks stock1("Baker Hughes Inc.", "BKR", 24.86f);
    Stocks stock2("Schlumberger Technology Corp", "SLB", 34.20f);
    Stocks stock3("Halliburton Energy Services", "HAL", 23.94f);
    Stocks stock4("Amazon", "AMZN", 3373.63f);
    Stocks stock5("Microsoft", "MSFT", 259.29f);
    
    myList.push_front(stock1);
    myList.push_back(stock2);
    myList.push_back(stock3);
    myList.push_back(stock4);
    myList.push_back(stock5);

     for(std::list<Stocks>::iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr!= myList.end(); itr++)
        {
         Stocks stock = *itr;
         stock.display();
        }
    vector<Stocks *> myVector(5);
    int i = 0;
    for (std::list<Stocks>::iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr!= myList.end(); itr++)
    {
        Stocks stock = *itr;
        myVector[i] = &stock;
        i++;
    }
    Stocks * temp = new Stocks();
    temp->companyName = "Google";
    temp->tickerSymbol = "GOOGL";
    temp->sharePrice = 2428.29;
    myVector[3] = temp;
   
    for (int i = myVector.size(); i < 0; i--)
    {
        myVector[i]->display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Stocks header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#ifndef STOCKS_H
#define STOCKS_H

class Stocks {
public:
    string companyName;
    string tickerSymbol;
    float sharePrice;
    
    Stocks();
    Stocks(string companyName, string tickerSymbol, float sharePrice);
    
    void display();
    virtual ~Stocks();
private:

};

#endif /* STOCKS_H */
```

Stocks source file

```
#include "Stocks.h"

Stocks::Stocks() {
    
    companyName = "";
    tickerSymbol = "";
    sharePrice = 0.0f;
}
Stocks::Stocks(string companyName, string tickerSymbol, float sharePrice)
{
    this->companyName = companyName;
    this->tickerSymbol = tickerSymbol;
    this->sharePrice = sharePrice;
}

void Stocks::display()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
    cout << "Company Name: " << companyName << endl;
    cout << "Ticker Symbol: " << tickerSymbol << endl;
    cout << "Share Price: "  << sharePrice << endl;
    
}
Stocks::~Stocks() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is in the loop

```
for (std::list<Stocks>::iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr!= myList.end(); itr++)
{
    Stocks stock = *itr;
    myVector[i] = &stock;
    i++;
}
```

Inside you define `stock` as a *locally scoped* variable, inside the scope of that loop only. Each time the loop iterates, the `stock` object is destructed and any pointer to it becomes invalid.

The simple solution is to make a pointer to the actual element from the list itself:

```
for (std::list<Stocks>::iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr!= myList.end(); itr++)
{
    myVector[i] = &*itr;
    i++;
}
```

There's also the problem with the condition in your printing loop:

```
for (int i = myVector.size(); i < 0; i--)
```

Since you initialize `i` to be equal to `myVector.size()` it will begin equal to `5` (which by the way is out of bounds of the vector), and as `5 < 0` is false the loop won't iterate.

The correct condition is to loop from size - 1 while `i` is *larger or equal* to `0`:

```
for (int i = myVector.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

---

For adding the elements to the vector I would also recommend using [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
for (auto& stock : myList)
{
    myVector[i++] = &stock;
}
```

Or you could use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to "transform" the elements from the list to the vector:

```
std::transform(begin(myList), end(myList), begin(myVector),
    [](Stocks& stock)
    {
        return &stock;
    });
```

Comment: Ok but now how do i get it to display the vector?

Comment: Nevermind I figured that out already. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nevermind I thought I did...i still cannot get it to display.

Comment: Nevermind yeah I got it thanks....

Comment: I see what I did wrong with my two loops. Bonehead mistake on the second one. But I didnt know you reference the address of a pointer...thanks for that

Comment: @eric1379 helpful thought-tool: A pointer is just another variable that happens to hold the location of some other object. You can do the same things to it you can do to other variables plus some limited arithmetic and, of course, accessing the object it points to.